# setting variables in apache flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm asking this question because I'm having trouble setting variables in apache flink. i would like to use a stream to fetch data with which i will initialize the variables i need for the second stream. The problem is that the streams execute in parallel, which results in a missing value when initializing the second stream. sample code:

```
KafkaSource<Object> mainSource1 = KafkaSource.<Object>builder()
      .setBootstrapServers(...)
      .setTopicPattern(Pattern.compile(...))
      .setGroupId(...)
      .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
      .setDeserializer(new ObjectDeserializer())
      .build();

DataStream<Market> mainStream1 = env.fromSource(mainSource, WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps(), "mainSource");


// fetching data from the stream and setting variables


Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffset = new HashMap<>();
endOffset.put(new TopicPartition("topicName", 0), offsetFromMainStream1);



KafkaSource<Object> mainSource2 = KafkaSource.<Object>builder()
      .setBootstrapServers(...)
      .setTopicPattern(Pattern.compile(...))
      .setGroupId(...)
      .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
      .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.offsets(endOffset))
      .setDeserializer(new ObjectDeserializer())
      .build();

DataStream<Market> mainStream2 = env.fromSource(mainSource, WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps(), "mainSource");

// further stream operations
```

I would like to call the first stream from which I will fetch the data and set it locally then I can use it in operations on the second stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use one Stream's data to control another Stream's behavior. The best way is to use the Broadcast state pattern.

This involves creating a `BroadcastStream` from `mainStream1`, and then connecting `mainStream2` to `mainStream1`. Now `mainStream2` can access the data from `mainStream1`.

Here is a high level example based on your code. I am assuming that the key is String.

```
// Broadcast Stream
MapStateDescriptor<String, Market> stateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor<>(
            "RulesBroadcastState",
            BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
            TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Market>() {}));
        
// broadcast the rules and create the broadcast state
BroadcastStream<Market> mainStream1BroadcastStream = mainStream1.keyBy(// key by Id).
                        .broadcast(stateDescriptor);

DataStream<Market> yourOutput = mainStream2
                 .connect(mainStream1BroadcastStream)
                 .process(            
                    new KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction<>() {
                         // You can access mainStream1 output and mainStream2 data here.
                     }
                 );
```

This concept is explained in detail here. The code is also a modified version shown here -
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/#the-broadcast-state-pattern

Comment: what if the first stream has data that we want to use when creating the second KafkaSource stream, for example, the offset of the end of the second stream, or the name of the file we need to create the sink? and in that case read data from the first stream before initializing the second stream and sink ?

Comment: If you are reading the first stream to configure the application components (sink) or the another stream's source, it is technically not a stream, just a datasource. Even if you read it as a stream, the application would need to restarted if the values changed. So for that you can just consume the variables using a Kafka Consumer, use the values to create the second  stream.